# How to stop sending duplicated HTTP GET request?

Tags: php, http, get, http-get, get-request

I am using following PHP code to send HTTP GET request to a URL, I am not sure why my script is sending another duplicate request following the first one when first response takes a little bit of time. (ex: > 1 seconds)

`$token = \JWT::encode($params, $secret_key);`

`header("Location: http://some_url?" . http_build_query(['t' => $token]));`

`exit();`

Comment: This code for sure does not send POST request.

Comment: My bad, its a GET request

Comment: No, this script only sends a redirect header. So what will happen is, when the actual request to the PHP script is made, it will redirect the caller (possibly the browser) to the new location, and that is all what it does. The browser will then issue a new GET request for the new location. It does not send a request from the script or anything, you'd probably want to use something like [http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php](file_get_contents) or [http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php](php-curl) for that.

Comment: @mvdwerve: I know that. I just wanted to see if all the variables are getting passed along to the requested url or not. I guess I am more curious to know why it does duplicate redirect with same data when first get request takes more than a second or so? Please note that, it works fine when there is no waiting time for response. Just messes up when its not. But I am going to try the file_get_contents way.

Comment: Because if there's a wait time the user is going to hit refresh..

Comment: @developerwjk: Ah, that wont be a case. I'll be using task queue.

Comment: @YaminNoor Is a browser making the request to the original script or some application/library? By the way I've really messed up those links, accidentally reversed the markdown. Oops. Cant change that now.

Comment: @mvdwerve: Yes, currently I am using a browser to do the redirect. No worries, I know how to use file_get_contents and php curl.